# Search and replace regular expression for keeping numbers intact and copying them

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

I'm using Dreamweaver to replace a line of code that looks like this

```
123, //hotspot topValue
```

with a line of code that looks like this

```
[123, 123, 123], //hotspot topValue
```

I suck at regular expressions.. And what makes it even more difficult is that the number I need to keep unchanged is not always three digits but can be sometimes 0 too.

In that case it should go from

```
0, //hotspot topValue
```

to

```
[0, 0, 0], //hotspot topValue
```

So basically I always take the number on the line that is commented //hotspot topValue and put it inside an array and duplicate it two times.

Is this possible with regular expressions in the find and replace panel? I read that Dreamweaver uses Javascript regular expressions if it helps.

Comment: By what logic is the number being converted into an array and repeated three times? Is that always constant? And is this internal Dreamweaver development, or is it in an actual generated HTML document?

Comment: David the point is that on some occasions I need to go in later and tweak the other two numbers in the array but by default they should be same as the first value (so that my current code doesn't change if not necessary). The result is an actual html document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [dreamweaver's documentation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/regular_expressions_pt2.html).

The regular expression you are looking for would be:

```
Find: ([0-9]+), //hotspot topValue
Replace: [$1,$1,$1], //hotspot topValue
```

`[0-9]+` will match any number of characters `0,1,2,..,9` that occur at least once (`+` means one or more).  Brackets around it will make it a capture group, meaning that you can then use any content matched inside them as `$1`. The rest is obvious: match exactly `, //hotstop topValue`.

Alternatively you can use

```
Find: ([0-9]+), //(.+)
Replace: [$1,$1,$1], //$2
```

To match your number followed by any comment (although one must be present).

Comment: That's amazing! Thank you very much for this! I know I need to get a better grasp on regular expressions asap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use capturing groups:

- Search `(\d+), //(.*?)`
- Replace `[$1, $1, $1], //$2`

Comment: I like your solution, but do you really need `(.*?)`? This will virtually never be matched because of the lazy evaluation, right? I've tried it on [RegExr](http://regexr.com?31qck) and capture group 2 always comes empty (which isn't an issue because you're not really interested in this part but nonetheless)

Comment: Yes this was otherwise a good solution, but I specifically only need to replace lines with a comment //hoptspot topValue and not just any line with a comment.